# JqGrid programmatic showing and hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm hide the grid portion when the user clicks the arrow element. It seems that setting the GridState to hidden doesn't do anything.  I'm also resizing the grid based on if the jqgrid is already collapsed or if it's expanded.  I'm not able to make changes to the jqgrid JS file, so how would it be able to accomplish this task?

```
function resizer(element)
    {
        var element1 = $('#Table').height();

            if (element.className == "ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-s") {
                $('#Table').css({ height: element - 77 });
                //initializedExtendersGrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
                $(extendersGridSelector).jqGrid('setGridState', 'hidden');
                //$('.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').hide();
            }
            if (element.className == "ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n") {
                $('#Table').css({ height: element + 77 });
                $(extendersGridSelector).jqGrid('setGridState', 'hidden');
                //$('.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').hide();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. At one side you click arrow grid icon in grid header to hide the grid on other side you tell us that setGridState does not do anything. My question is where and how you call the function you posed?

Comment: sorry about that. I added a listener function for when that arrow is clicked.